# View Model Dependency Injection

Tags: ios, mvvm, dependency-injection, viewmodel, rx-swift

`ItemDetailViewModel` is initialized with the following signature:

```
init(item: Item, didPressButton: Observable<Void>, api: FirebaseAPI)
```

It is initialized in `ItemDetailViewController`, which gets an `Item` from segue of source controller. Im realizing that `ItemDetailViewController` is technically the `View`, so it should not have `Item` as a stored property. How else do I transfer `Item` to `ItemDetailViewModel`? This also means that `ItemListViewController` shouldn't have a `selectedItem` stored property to use in `prepareFor(segue:)`.

**Potential Solution**

So when a `CollectionView Cell` is tapped in `ItemListViewController` (source controller), it should trigger `ItemListViewModel` through binding to store `Item`, and then `perform segue`. Meanwhile, in `prepareForSegue` I use `ItemListViewModel` to initialize `ItemDetailViewModel` with `Item`. Ok.. That could work.

How do I handle the button taps, which changes its image on each tap? through a function?

What is the proper way to initialize `view models` and `inject dependencies`?

Comment: Your view model should not be concerned with button taps.  That is for the view or view controller to process.  You should create the `ItemDetailViewModel` as you propose and pass it to the `ItemDetailViewController` via the segue.  When a button is tapped the view controller receives that notification and updates the `ItemDetailViewModel`.

Comment: Ok, so when I subscribe to button taps, inside subscription block I'll call a method on my viewModel to handle behavior. Thanks

Comment: The `didPressButton` observable is not a button tap. Rather it's a "reason for the view model to do something," which may or may not be due to a button tap. Therefore, the view model is not concerned with button taps in this question. It's better to just pass the button observable directly to the view model because that will remove logic from the view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object that needs three pieces of data to be constructed, but one of the pieces of data comes from a different source than the other two. This is a good time to use higher-order functions.

```
struct ItemDetailViewModel {
    static func factory(item: Item, api: FirebaseAPI) -> (_ action: Observable<Void>) -> ItemDetailViewModel {
        return { action in 
            return ItemDetailViewModel(item: item, didPressButton: action, api: api)
        }
    }
}
```

Your view controller would accept the result of this function:

```
class ItemDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var viewModelFactory: (Observable<Void>) -> ItemDetailViewController = { _ in fatalError("factory called before provided.") }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let viewModel = viewModelFactory(myButton.rx.tap.asObservable())
        // bind output to view model
    }
}
```

Then in your previous view controller's prepare for segue:

```
if let controller = segue.destinationViewController as? ItemDetailViewController {
    controller.viewModelFactory = ItemDetailViewModel.factory(item: anItem, api: api)
}
```